# Web API OData v4 only gives 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm at the end of my rope, I've run out of things to Google.  I don't know which piece of the below could be wrong?

localhost:29197/odata/Tests/ returns 404

localhost:29197/odata?$metadata returns 404 (or is it localhost:29197/odata/$metadata)

Same 404 with or without the route prefix.

**Controller:**

```
namespace MvcApplication.Api
{
    public class TestsController : ODataController
    {
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Test> Get()
        {
            return new List<Test>() {new Test() {Id = 1}}.AsQueryable();
        } 
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig:**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata", routePrefix: "odata", model: GetEdmModel());
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        builder.EntitySet<Test>("Tests");

        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return model;
    }
}
```

`WebApiConfig.Register` comes before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`

The Web.config contains `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment (OWIN running on OS X). Looks like its an IIS or Windows config issue.

Comment: hmm, I am hosting in IIS Express on localhost

Comment: BTW, the correct URIs for your service are `http://localhost:29197/odata/$metadata` and `http://localhost:29197/odata/Tests`.

Comment: Doesn't work either, but good to confirm, thank you!

Comment: Did you register WebApi config in Application start event? `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`, also do you have any other non-odata APIs in your project, are they working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that, you have registered WebApi conffig in Application start event in global.asax.cs like below -

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`.  The other isn't recognized.  I've seen both ways online, but I'm not sure what's behind the difference?

Comment: Oh... the difference is I don't have `Web API 2.2` 5.x installed, I still had 4.0.  I thought installing `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData` would update it.... idk whether to laugh, cry, or curse.... Thanks!